# How to INSERT strings with Vietnamese characters into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I cannot `INSERT` Vietnamese strings into the database that expects char utf8.
There is an error with the font.

Ex:

> title: Lê Việt Hải Dương
>   info: Dương IT 911

Here is my code:

```
$title =  $_POST['title'];
$info =  $_POST['title'];
$query = "INSERT INTO `nick` ( `title`,  `info`) VALUES ('$title','$info')";
$insert_count = $db->exec($query);
```

This is what appears in the database:

For title:

> Lê Vi?t H?i D??ng

For info:

> D??ng IT 911

Comment: Try changing the table's column collation to `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: I had try, it not work

Comment: Collation is irrelevant; charset is.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored and look for "question mark"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope these help you !

---

1. First Check That if your file saved in utf-8 !
2. Put your mysql character encoding on utf-8 !

   mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
3. Now if you use mysql go to phpmyadmin and select your database and then 
   go to operations tab and in the collation section change your collation in utf-8
4. The last thing i can tell to you is to check your table , collation ! open your tables and go to operations tab and find collation , and change it !!

---

Good luck ! I hope it helps you <3